# How to retrieve information from JIRA using webhooks in an ASP.Net MVC application?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, jira, webhooks

I am using an MVC application that will send an email to **JIRA** with the information required to create an **Issue** in JIRA.

This is all works successfully but the next step is to retrieve the information in a page.  Currently I am displaying the information that was sent by retrieving it from the database.

The problem is that I also need to retrieve the **KEY** and the **status** of the issue.  This cannot be just entered as the user will not know what they are, it has to be done in JIRA.

Originally I was going to use an API to get the information from JIRA but because the JIRA site is not hosted online the API does not meet the **Access-Control-Allow-Headers"** Header.

I was told that I would have to use **webhooks** to get the information but I am unsure about how to go about this.

I know that I have to first register the webhook which I am doing **Via the JIRA Administration UI.**  What I what to know is how can I retrieve that information in my application using webhooks, I know the webhooks must have **a friendly name** for the webhook created, **the URL** where the **callback** should be sent.

**The scope** of the webhook and **the events** to post to the URL, either "all events" or a specific set of events.

I also know that the Post function web hooks will not fire if added to the Create Issue workflow transition. We recommend that you configure your web hook to fire from the issue_created event instead.

So how can I successfully retrieve this information, I am currently trying this:

```
  Public Function Webhook() As ActionResult
        Dim status As String = "Status"
        If Request("secret") <> status Then
            Response.StatusCode = 403
            Return Content("Invalid status secret")
        End If
        If Request("event") = "incoming_messages" Then
            Dim Key As String = Request("Key")
            Dim jiraStatus As String = Request("status")

            Dim reply As Dictionary(Of String, Object) = New Dictionary(Of String, Object)()
            reply("content") = "Thanks for your submission!"

            Dim result As Dictionary(Of String, Object) = New Dictionary(Of String, Object)()
            result("messages") = New Object() {reply}

            Return Json(result)

        Else
            Response.StatusCode = 400
            Return Content("Unknown event")
        End If

        Return View()
    End Function
```

But I am pretty sure I am doing it wrong, what steps do I need to follow to do this correctly?

**Update**

Where should my Webhook URL fire to currently I am sending it to RequestB.in for testing which is working but where should I fire it to get the information in my MVC application? Should it fire to the MVC application, if so where should it fire to.

How can I process the Json payload currently in my MVC application, I am trying to deserialize it but I have not done this before and am unsure how to connect the Json Payload with the application. This is what I have tried so far:

```
        Request.InputStream.Position = 0
        Request.InputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)
        Using reader = New StreamReader(Request.InputStream)

            Dim jiraJson = reader.ReadToEnd()
            Dim contentType As String = Request.ContentType
            Dim body = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jiraJson)

            Try
                Select Case DirectCast(body.key, String)
                    Case ""
                        Return Json(jiraJson)

                    Case Else
                        Return Json(jiraJson)


                End Select
            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try
        End Using

        Return View()
```

I am unsure what to place in switch statement and also how to return the json and then display it, how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, a high level process of how this should work would be :

- An email is sent to Jira.
- An issue is created under the given project, which triggers the webhook.
- The webhook will POST a JSON payload to the URL you've specified.
- The URL should be a public route within your MVC application that consumes and processes the request.

So given where you're already at, all you need to consume the webhook is a publicly accessible MVC route. Let's say you have a controller named "JiraUpdateController", and on that controller exists a method called "ProcessWebhook" :

```
public class JiraUpdateController : Controller
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Set our default base logger for the update tasks
    /// </summary>
    private static readonly Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    public static Logger Log
    {
        get { return logger; }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ProcessWebhook()
    {
         // Process the JSON payload here accordingly.
    }    
}
```

Now, you need to set this as the URL that the webhook should post to. Ultimately it should look something like :

http://internal.company.com/JiraUpdate/ProcessWebhook

I've done something very similar to this, so here's a couple things to keep in mind.

- Make sure you're setting the webhook to a minimal scope. If this is something you want to trigger across all projects whenever an issue is created in any of them, you're going to have quite a few requests going to the ProcessWebhook endpoint. Try to limit the projects to just the ones you need, and the event to only the "issue created" event.
- If you don't already have a public endpoint for testing, you should definitely check out [RequestBin](http://requestb.in/). What this will allow you to do, is setup a temporary URL for the webhook, so you can see exactly what the JSON payload from JIRA will look like. From there, build your business logic in the ProcessWebhook method, and you should be good to go. To use RequestBin, just go to the site, generate a URL, and set that as the Webhook URL. Create an issue in JIRA under the project you're working with, and you should see a large JSON payload go to that RequestBin URL - this will give you a feel for exactly what the JSON looks like and how to serialize it into a workable construct.

Comment: Okay - just to be sure, are you referring to the internal.company.com link or the RequestBin link? The former is just something I made up, as an example.

Comment: Okay cool, just wanted to make sure. Let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: I am unsure about processing the JSON in the ProcessWebhook, I am trying to deserialize the JSON, and for the webhook URL where should it fire so that the application can retrieve the information.  I don't now how to connect the to things together.

Comment: Ultimately you want the webhook to POST to your "JiraUpdate/ProcessWebhook" endpoint, but to do that, you need to get your app hosted somewhere where the request can reach it. For example, let's say you have a web server within your building called "jiraintegration". Also, let's say you've installed your app on this server, and it's running in IIS under an application named "JiraProcessor". Your webhook should then POST to http://jiraintegration.yourcompany.com/JiraProcessor/JiraUpdate/ProcessWebhook

Comment: Your endpoint is strictly there for consumption. To test it, just grab the JSON payload out of RequestBin, create a Fiddler request with the same payload, and POST it locally to your app running on your machine - this allows you to test your serialization - I use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WebEventHook>(json);`, which gives me a nice object to work with and perform business logic on.

Comment: I have the app installed on a server called server1/TestSites/IssueTracker/  so should it post to the application name (IssueTracker is the name of the app) or to an index in the application (issueTracker/home/issue iss an inedx that I what it to display the data)  and can this be done also on localhost for testing purposes

Comment: @X3074861X The RequestBin/Fiddler combo works well, but if you want something a bit less manual, you can use a Runscope proxy URL and relay the request through Runscope and onto the final URL.  This allows you to inspect the webhook payload and test serialization.  If your app is behind a firewall, you'll need use something like NGrok to tunnel the request.

Comment: Okay, in that case it should POST to server1/TestSites/IssueTracker/JiraUpdate/ProcessWebhook - it is possible to test it locally, either go the RequestBin\Fiddler route, or check @Darrel Miller's suggestion on using Runscope proxy url.

Comment: @DarrelMiller is there any other way of relaying on the request other than using Runscope because that requires you to sign up for a trial and this application is for an actual business project so after the trial is done the application still needs to work

Comment: @ciaran82 After the trial expires you go to a permanent free plan which gives you 25K requests per month.  Also, you don't need to leave the relay there.  Just change the callback URL and Runscope will be out of the loop.  You can just use it when you need to debug.

Comment: so just to be clear, am I right in saying that my webhook should post to the application on the server, but before that I will post to RequestBin then using the Json Payload and either Runscope or Fiddler I send it to my application then serialize the data so I can display it in a format that is suitable, then in the actual application on the server any time a webhook url is posted it will display then in the application because of the way I have already performed the necessary business logic in the application previously

Comment: Yes. The difference between using Fiddler\RequestBin Vs. Runscope\nGrok is that the Runscope proxy would allow you to test in real time. However, capturing the payload in RequestBin, and simulating the POST in fiddler is the same exact thing. Once you know your business logic is solid, and you can properly process the webhook payload, deploy your application and change the webhook URL in Jira to that of your "server1/TestSites/IssueTracker/JiraUpdate/ProcessWebhook" endpoint.

Comment: @X3074861X one final question which piece of this information will constantly listen for the webhook that was fired?

Comment: That would be your MVC application - as long as it's up and running, those POST requests should hit your endpoint and be processed accordingly. It's basically just a consumer waiting to receive information.